# iTunes connect screenshot order

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am currently submitting an app with iTunes connect. I've seen on some websites that you need to post the screenshots in reverse order of how you want them to be displayed, but many of those posts are kind of old. When I'm uploading screenshots now, I can drag and drop to change the image order. Will the first screenshot be the first viewed in the App Store, or do I still need to order them in reverse order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first screenshot is the first one displayed in the App Store, yes. Those guides are out of date.

Comment: My last uploaded screenshot is being shown as the first/default one. The order is mixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted many apps to the app store, and I have found that none of the screenshots are reorganized, so it should probably not happen when you are posting it.

Good job for posting your app!

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 8 first and second screenshots are displayed on app store app on iPhone as main screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to post in reverse order. iTunes connect has been changed, for the better, and now it is not necessary to post in reverse order. The advice you received to post in reverse order is definitely out of date. For more information I would advise reading apple's distribution guide.