# iPhone App Store Screenshot Order

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

In iTunes Connect, the first screenshot (on left) is not showing up as the first screenshot in the App Store. In one case the 3rd screenshot in  iTunes Connect shows up 1st on the App Store and in another case the 4th screenshot is 1st on the App Store. Does anyone know how to specify the order of images?

I found this question, that says the 1st screenshot in iTunes Connect should be 1st on the App Store, but that is not the case for my 2 apps.

[iTunes connect screenshot order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462753/itunes-connect-screenshot-order)

Comment: The screenshot order is the same as in iTunes Connect, so sure about that, maybe you can delete all pictures and re-upload again, good luck.

Comment: I updated the pictures in iTunes Connect.  I know it can take a while for the updates to flow to the App Store. I'll keep checking to see if that worked.

Comment: I agree with David L. I too an facing a similar problem. My last uploaded screenshot is being shown as the first/default one. The order is mixed.

Comment: I deleted and reloaded as Veelian suggested and they show up in the right order now. I'm not sure what caused the issue originally.

Comment: @Veelian if you convert your comment to an answer, I will accept the answer so this post will show up as answered.  Thanks for your help.